# Finding $a$ such that $a^2x^2+3x-5\frac{1}{a}=0$ has exactly one solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For what value of $a$ would the following function have exactly one solution? 
>   $$a^2x^2+3x-5\frac{1}{a}=0$$

I know that it needs to become 
$$\frac{3}{2}x^2+3x+\frac{3}{2}=0$$ 
but how can one find value of parameter $a$ for this to happen ?

Comment: How do you know that “it needs to become ...?” The two equations are inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exactly one solution, we need $D=0$ i.e. $$3^2 -4\cdot a^2\cdot\left(-\frac 5a\right)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation of parabola: $y=a^2x^2+3x-\frac{5}{a}$ can be rewritten as follows
$$\left(x+\frac{3}{2a^2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(y+\frac{5}{a}+\frac{9}{4a^2}\right)\equiv X^2=4AY$$
The given quadratic equation: $a^2x^2+3x-\frac{5}{a}=0$ will have exactly one solution if above upward parabola just touches the X-axis where $y=0$ i.e. its vertex lies on X-axis hence
$$-\frac{5}{a}-\frac{9}{4a^2}=0\iff \color{blue}{a=-\frac{9}{20}}$$